How to model relationships which need more than one foreign key
Im working on a library providing an EntityFramework interface to SQLite databases generated by a genealogy program (RootsMagic).
RootsMagic stores  persons and families in two tables. The Families table contains entries for each family in which a person is member as father or mother (children are modeled in yet another table). A person can be a member of zero, one or more families. Entries in the Families table have at least one person (FatherId or MotherID)
Here a reduced schema:
Persons       Families
---------     ----------
INT  Id       INT Id
INT  sex      INT FatherID
TEXT Name     INT MotherID
              

And here an example:
Persons

ID  sex  Name
-------------
1   0    Father1
2   0    Son1
3   1    Grandmother 
4   0    Grandfather
5   1    Mother1
6   1    Daughter1
7   1    Mother2
8   1    Daughter2

Families

ID FatherID MotherID
-------------------
1  4        3
2  1        5
3  1        7


Family 1 models the Grandmother / Grandfather family
Family 2 models the Father1 / Mother1 family and
Family 3: the second family of Father1 with Mother2

To make access to the families easy for users, I'd like to have
a Families relationship in the Personmodel which lists all the families where a person is member of (as father or mother). In the example it should return families 2 and 3 for the person 1 (Father), family 2 for Person 5 (Mother1) and family 3 for person 7 (Mother2).
It is of course not difficult to get the families by a query like db.Families.Where(f => f.FatherID == person.Id || f.MotherID == person.Id). But, I'd prefer a direct access from the Person model
To work around this I added a separate _familyF (person is member as father) and a separate _familyM (person is member as mother) relationships to a person via the corresponding FatherID and MotherID foreign keys in Families. I then added a unmapped Families property which returns the union of both lists.
This is kind of working but usage is very inconvenient. Here the corressponding code:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace dbexperiment.Models;

public partial class Family
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? FatherID { get; set; }
    public long? MotherID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Father { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Mother { get; set; }
}

public partial class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Family> _familiesF { get; set; } = new List<Family>();
    private ICollection<Family> _familiesM { get; set; } = new List<Family>();
    // return a union of both family collections
    public ICollection<Family> Families => _familiesF.Union(_familiesM).ToList();
}

public class CTX : DbContext
{  
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)=> optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("test.db");
       
    public DbSet<Family> Families { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }    

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Family>(entity =>
        {           
            entity.HasOne(f => f.Father).WithMany("_familiesF").HasForeignKey(f => f.FatherID);
            entity.HasOne(f => f.Mother).WithMany("_familiesM").HasForeignKey(f => f.MotherID);                      
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
        {   
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Families);            
        });       
    }
}

While this works in principle it is very inconvenient to use:
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
     using (var db = new CTX())
     {
         // var personsWithFamilies = db.Persons.Include(p=>p.Families).Where(p => p.Families.Any()); // <== preferred
         var personsWithFamilies = (db.Persons.Include("_familiesF").Include("_familiesM")).ToList().Where(p => p.Families.Any());

         foreach (var person in personsWithFamilies)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
         }
     };
}

Is there a better solution for such cases?
Constraint: Since the database is generated by a third party program it should not be changed.

Why does the family have a father or mother? Shouldn't the person have a father and mother? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of how you want to specify the relationship between the Person entity and the Family entity. Add example data to make it clear what you are trying to model (including any edge cases, which are problematic to model).

@Progman I edited the question to hopefully be more clear.

So in your model i can be the father in one family and the mother in another Or i can be the Mother and Father at the same time in one family?

@Ralf the database structure does not prevent this. but the program which generates the data does.  So it is save to assume that the FatherID corresponds to a male person and the MotherID to a female person. The Person Table also includes a column for the gender of the person which didn't seem relevant here. But if it helps, this information could also be used.

Lazy loading proxies approach
One option may be using lazy loading proxies in which case you can remove all Include's. This can be enabled in CTX by adding the following.
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
}

Your new query wıll be
var personsWithFamilies = db.Persons.ToList().Where(p => p.Families.Any());

Optional optimization: Here, you are calling ToList() before Where, because otherwise, it will throw an exception as ef core doesn't know how to generate the query with Person.Families property. Please read projectables in the 3rd approach to handle this kind of issue. This may be important because currently you are loading all persons and this may lead to bad performance.
In this first approach please keep in mind that it will make a new request to database for each property you read if it is not set in the original call. In other words, it will make another request to database for each property you have to call Include when you are not using lazy loading proxies.

Using extension methods for includes
Another approach may be adding extension methods for the includes and use/reuse those extension methods rather than calling Include in the caller methods. To do this, you can convert private properties in Person to internal and add an extension method in the same project with Person
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Person> IncludeFamilies(this IQueryable<Person> persons)
    {
        return persons.Include("_familiesF").Include("_familiesM");
    }        
}

Then, your query will be
var personsWithFamilies = db.Persons.IncludeFamilies().ToList().Where(p => p.Families.Any());

If you prefer to use [Projectable] which is explained in the 3rd approach, then you can move ToList() to the end of the query. Also, in this case, you may not need to call include methods if you will not use families in your code after you fetch the persons.

Mapping database objects to dto's in the query
A third but probably the best solution is you can map your Person object to a dto like PersonDto in your query before calling ToList().
var personsWithFamilies = db.Persons.Select(p => new PersonDto 
{
    Name = p.Name,
    Families = p._familiesF.Union(p._familiesM).ToList()
})
.Where(personDto => personDto.Families.Any());

With this approach you don't need Families property in Person class. However, if you don't like the idea of putting p._familiesF.Union(p._familiesM).ToList() logic in the query there is a solution for that one as well. I am using a third party library that supports projections in the database objects. This is by simply adding [Projectable] attribute to Person.Families property.
public partial class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Family> _familiesF { get; set; } = new List<Family>();
    private ICollection<Family> _familiesM { get; set; } = new List<Family>();
    // return a union of both family collections
    [Projectable]
    public ICollection<Family> Families => _familiesF.Union(_familiesM).ToList();
}

Now, you can do your mapping easier.
var personsWithFamilies = db.Persons.Select(p => new PersonDto 
{
    Name = p.Name,
    Families = p.Families
})
.Where(personDto => personDto.Families.Any());

I am using the following package for [Projectable] attributes.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.Projectables/3.0.4?_src=template

Thanks, this is very useful information.  I'm aware of lazy loading. But, since the database sizes can be anything beteween a few hundred and a few hundred thousend persons I thought it might be best to let the user decide about lazy or eager loading.  The includes as such are not the problem, I just don't like that the user needs to include those helper collections (_familiesF/M) instead of just Families. So, if possible I'd like to get rid of those collections if possible.  Anyway, I'll play around with your suggestions. I definitely like the  Projectable approach.

Can you elaborate on your 'Using extension methods for includes' method?

@luni64 I edited  Using extension methods for includes section.
